# Short Story. Man sells his soul to the devil who arrives by train. Gets a watch which can stop time in exchange

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, souls

The man is homeless. The devil arrives by train wearing a conductor's uniform.

The devil offers him any wish he desires in exchange for his soul when he dies. They make the bargain and he wishes the ability to stop time at one especially happy moment. The devil gives him a watch that can stop time.

He becomes rich and sucessful. Has many happy moments but always thinks something better will come along so does not use the watch.Then he dies.

The devil turns up in the train again to take him to hell.

> He uses the watch to freeze time on the train on the way to hell. Has a very happy eternity with all the sinners on the train that never reaches hell.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/228423/20774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[That Hell-bound Train](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Hell-Bound_Train)* (1958) by Robert Bloch.

> Martin is a young hobo with a fondness for trains. One night, as he is considering whether to abandon crime, a large unmarked black train pulls up beside him. The train conductor offers Martin anything he wants, in return for which he will "ride that Hell-Bound Train" when he dies. Martin requests the power to stop time, which he plans to use at the happiest time of his life. The conductor accedes to this request; however, over the years that follow, Martin discovers that he cannot choose which moment is his happiest. In the end, he dies, never having stopped time, and indeed boards the train. However, he likes the sinful look of the passengers and chooses to stop time then and there. The train never reaches the depot and Martin, now the brakeman, finally finds happiness.

Comment: Yes this is it, it is a duplicate of the question you linked to in your comment. Will accept your answer when the system will let me. Thank you.